# Gazebo with multiple odometery frames

Tags: gazebo, navigation, simulation, odometry, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to put together a multiple (n=2) Husky robot simulation for testing purposes.  I am struggling with getting the namespaces and tf_prefixes setup in a consistent way.  Following previous discussions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/226274/is-it-possible-to-use-robot_localization-for-multiple-robots/%22title%22) which builds on the single Husky tutorials, I have been able to get almost there.  At this point I believe the gist of my issue is how to tell Gazebo to use a tf_prefix for the "odom" frame.

My understanding is that robot_localization (ekf_localization) takes the imu and odom data generated from Gazebo to generate the odometry messages on the odometry/filtered topic.  For the imu I am able to edit the robot_description parameters in the xacro file to have a frameId for each robot.  For example...

```
<gazebo>
      <plugin name="imu_controller" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
        <robotNamespace>/r1</robotNamespace>
        <frameId>r1_tf/base_link</frameId>
       ...
      </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

This works as expected and the ekf_localization node is able to work with the imu observations.

What I don't know how to do is to prescribe the same frame prefix (e.g., r1_tf) for the odometry generated by Gazebo.  Is there a way to tell Gazebo what tf frame to use for the odometry messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228380/gazebo-with-multiple-odometery-frames/) by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-03-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you nbeyers.  That was the hint I needed to get everything working.  it was not clear to me, and is still not completely clear, how the controller_manager loads these controllers into gazebo, but for now I have a working example.

I was able to avoid having multiple control.yaml files for each robot by setting the base_frame_id parameter directly, overwriting the value form the control.yaml file.

```
 <rosparam command="load" file="$(find husky_control)/config/control.yaml" />
 <rosparam param="husky_velocity_controller/base_frame_id" subst_value="True">$(arg tfpre)/base_link</rosparam>
  <node name="base_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="husky_joint_publisher husky_velocity_controller --shutdown-timeout 3"/>
```

This lead to a somewhat satisfying result where I could spawn multiple Huskies succinctly by only changing one launch file.  Something like this...

```
<group ns="h1">
  <include file="$(find nre_simmultihusky)/launch/husky.launch">
    <arg name="namespace" value="h1" />
    <arg name="initX" value="2" />
    <arg name="initY" value="2" />
    <arg name="initYaw" value="0" />
   </include>
 </group>

<group ns="h2">
  <include file="$(find nre_simmultihusky)/launch/husky.launch">
    <arg name="namespace" value="h2" />
    <arg name="initX" value="-3" />
    <arg name="initY" value="-3" />
    <arg name="initYaw" value="3.14" />
  </include>
</group>
```

I wish I could find a way to cleanly only have to enter the namespace (e.g., 'h1') once instead of having to repeat it in group and arg tags.

I've posted my solution here https://github.com/bsb808/nre_simmultihusky

I have to say, I was pretty surprised by how much effort it took to change the namespace and tf_prefix in all the appropriate places to get this to run correctly.  I'm new to ROS, but I expected the use of the group tag with a namespace to percolate through components better.  I also didn't appreciate the headache that the propagating the tf_prefix appropriately would be - to a new person it seems redundant with the namespace.

Thanks again - glad to get it up and running.

---

Originally posted by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) with karma: 108 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on my previous experience and the question that you linked to, I've found a few places where I needed to change the frame_id parameter. The first is in the initial launch file where you configure the namespaces. It'll look something like this:

```
  <group ns="husky1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="husky1" /> 
    <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/multi_spawn_husky.launch">
      <arg name="laser_enabled" value="$(arg laser_enabled)"/>
      <arg name="ur5_enabled" value="$(arg ur5_enabled)"/>
      <arg name="kinect_enabled" value="$(arg kinect_enabled)"/>
      <arg name="x" value="-7.0"/>
      <arg name="y" value="0.0"/>
      <arg name="namespace" value="husky1"/>
    </include>
  </group>
```

I'm assuming you've done this. This covers all the transforms within the model for the robot, but not odometry. The odometry transform is broadcast by the robot_localization node and this gets data from a couple of other topics, specifically **imu/data** and **husky_controller_velocity/odom**. You'll have to configure both of these as well. For the IMU, what you did is correct; set the **frameId** tag in the **huskyN.gazebo.xacro** file for each robot. (As a side note, if you plan on using GPS, you'll also want to add the tag for that as well. It's not included by default, but the **frameId** tag can be used in the same way as with the IMU).

Finally, and I think this is where you're problems arise, you'll have to configure the husky_velocity_controller. This is started in the **control.launch** file in the **husky_control** package, which loads a set of parameters in **control.yaml**. I've edited mine to look like this:

```
husky_joint_publisher:
  type: "joint_state_controller/JointStateController"
  publish_rate: 50

husky_velocity_controller:
  type: "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  left_wheel: ['front_left_wheel', 'rear_left_wheel']
  right_wheel: ['front_right_wheel', 'rear_right_wheel']
  publish_rate: 50
  pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03]
  twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03]
  cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25

  # Base frame_id
  base_frame_id: husky1/base_link
...
```

Notice the last line that I showed. That's where to set the frame ID for the velocity controller odometry. For me, I wasn't sure how to pass arguments to a .yaml file, so I just made a separate file for each robot and called the correct one using an argument in **control.launch** just like I did for the .xacro files. Now your IMU and velocity-based odometry should have a frame recognized by robot_localization and **huskyN/odometry/filtered** topic for each robot should work as it did with the single husky simulator.

---

Originally posted by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) with karma: 161 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2